# How to read unmerged column in Pandas and transpose them

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a excel with multiple sheets in the below format. I need to create a single dataframe by concatenating all the sheets, unmerging the cell and then transposing them into a column based on the sheet

**Sheet 1:**
[image]

**Sheet 2:**
[image]

**Final Dataframe should look like below
Result expected - I need the below format with an extra coulmn as below**

[image]

Code So far:
Reading File:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('/Users/john/Desktop/Internal/Raw Files/Med/Dig/File_2017_2022.xlsx', sheet_name=None, skiprows=1))
```

Creating Column :

```
df_1 = pd.concat([df.assign(name=n) for n,df in dfs.items()])
```

Comment: Is possible create sample excel sheet and share with anonymize data (e.g. 2 sheets, 5 rows * 5 column in each)? Because with picture (also with text) is hard to know what is real structure in excel data.

Comment: Sure, How do I attach an excel file here?

Comment: you can use dropbox, wetransfer, gdocs...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see an option for dropbox or any transfers. Could you help me on the same

Comment: Simple copy link of shared data and post link to comment.

Comment: Inout file :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRWsS67GuuogCaNiBR8kZ_cn7FOeiJRRe2fwpXGtSr5AXxbILTWA3FGpSHt4ZZ-92N7xNc3JWyk0aR8/pubhtml

Comment: Required Output format : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTfdcqkeXW6z3gt3ehRMSJyykQJpqq58cr5Pw4MFI98AU-zh0Hj4OfHBqnH6OzFbUZDUiH6pV14IuGN/pubhtml

Comment: Is possible download data like excel from youtr link? For me not working.

Comment: Input Link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRZK4QH5CFvK6sUMFb1byEjQ3EORx7PqdCarFCaBmJk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Expected format : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y8QOmEBVxYfoHRtslAujKJDb9RTbO4r40h2xDdB5Vz0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is better, now `You need access` error. Need set permissions

Comment: Request was sent.

Comment: I have granted you the access. Meanwhile, Expected format with access link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y8QOmEBVxYfoHRtslAujKJDb9RTbO4r40h2xDdB5Vz0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Super, working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with `header=[0,1]` for MultiIndex by first 2 rows of header and `index_col=[0,1]` for `MultiIndex` by first 2 columns, so possible in loop reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), add new column, use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and last set index names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with convert to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('Input_V1.xlsx',sheet_name=None, header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1])

df_1 = (pd.concat([df.stack(0).assign(name=n) for n,df in dfs.items()])
          .rename_axis(index=['Date','WK','Brand'], columns=None)
          .reset_index())
df_1.insert(len(df_1.columns) - 2, 'Campaign', df_1.pop('Campaign'))
```

---

```
print (df_1)
          Date       WK Brand   A   B   C   D             E             F   G  \
0   2017-10-02  Week 40   ABC NaN NaN NaN NaN  56892.800000  83431.664000 NaN   
1   2017-10-09  Week 41   ABC NaN NaN NaN NaN      0.713716      0.474025 NaN   
2   2017-10-16  Week 42   ABC NaN NaN NaN NaN      0.025936      0.072500 NaN   
3   2017-10-23  Week 43   ABC NaN NaN NaN NaN      0.182677      0.926731 NaN   
4   2017-10-30  Week 44   ABC NaN NaN NaN NaN      0.755607      0.686115 NaN   
..         ...      ...   ...  ..  ..  ..  ..           ...           ...  ..   
99  2018-03-26  Week 13   PQR NaN NaN NaN NaN  47702.000000  12246.000000 NaN   
100 2018-04-02  Week 14   PQR NaN NaN NaN NaN  38768.000000  46498.000000 NaN   
101 2018-04-09  Week 15   PQR NaN NaN NaN NaN  35917.000000  45329.000000 NaN   
102 2018-04-16  Week 16   PQR NaN NaN NaN NaN  39639.000000  51343.000000 NaN   
103 2018-04-23  Week 17   PQR NaN NaN NaN NaN  50867.000000  30119.000000 NaN   

      H   I   J             K             L Campaign name  
0   NaN NaN NaN      0.017888      0.697324      NaN  ABC  
1   NaN NaN NaN      0.457963      0.810985      NaN  ABC  
2   NaN NaN NaN      0.743030      0.253668      NaN  ABC  
3   NaN NaN NaN      0.038683      0.050028      NaN  ABC  
4   NaN NaN NaN      0.885567      0.712333      NaN  ABC  
..   ..  ..  ..           ...           ...      ...  ...  
99  NaN NaN NaN   9433.000000  17108.000000       WX  PQR  
100 NaN NaN NaN  12529.000000  23557.000000       WX  PQR  
101 NaN NaN NaN  20395.000000  44228.000000       WX  PQR  
102 NaN NaN NaN  55077.000000  45149.000000       WX  PQR  
103 NaN NaN NaN  45815.000000  35761.000000       WX  PQR  

[104 rows x 17 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a string column in the data which i missed. So now if I use my data. I'm getting multiple columns created for that string coulmn. I have edited the input file

Comment: @anaghas - For me working very well. Also with new column.

Comment: Yes I see the column Camp (String Column) but along with that i can see 11 columns generated like camp name.1, camp name.2, camp name.3.... camp name.11 with blank cells

Comment: @anaghas - Is same name `Camp` column for each sheet?

Comment: yes it is the same name

Comment: @anaghas - Because it is some data related problem. with sample data working well.

Comment: okay thanks for the help. Is this because the "camp" column has blank value in actual data?

Comment: could you please help me in fixing the multiple columns generated

Comment: @anaghas - Can you change input data for generate wrong ouput?

Comment: yes the updated input file link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YEYPxYkLT7jyBfXi2hUWQgbKS2G8P0mxk_8_GJ9tnQE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @anaghas - I check data and whats happens with missing values? In another words what is wrong with ouput from solution above?

Comment: @anaghas - I try sample data and it seems there are only NaNs columns, but there are data in another rows for these columns. Answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks its working fine, it was issue with the actual data file and not the campaign column

Answer (score 1):

I created my own version of your excel, which looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJXuD.png)

The code below is far from perfect but it should do fine as long as you do not have millions of sheets

```
# First, obtain all sheet names
full_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\.\Downloads\test.xlsx', 
sheet_name=None, skiprows=0)

# Store them into a list
sheet_names = list(full_df.keys())

# Create an empty Dataframe to store the contents from each sheet
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for sheet in sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\.\Downloads\test.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet, skiprows=0)
    # Get the brand name 
    brand = df.columns[1]

    # Remove the header columns and keep the numerical values only
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df[1:]
    df = df.iloc[:, 1:]

    # Set the brand name into a new column
    df['Brand'] = brand

    # Append into the final dataframe
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df])
```

Your final_df should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALkPi.png) once exported back to excel

EDIT: You might need to drop the dataframe's index upon saving it by using the *df.reset_index(drop=True)* function, to remove the first column shown in the image right above.

Comment: Thanks, but I still see empty columns (NaN) in the final output. Is there a different way to go about? Because the code I have so far tried is also giving me the same result

Comment: You may try now, I have modified the code to fit your exact example provided in the comments below.

Comment: No, the brand column has "brand name" as the only value